# jQuery hide/show div in home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a Google custom search, i want to show ads on home page when link is `www.mywebsite.com` and to hide the ads when the link is `https://www.mywebsite.com/?q=` how i can do this? Thanks

```
$(function(){

    var currPath = window.location.pathname; 

  $('.path').text('Current path is : '+ currPath);
  if(currPath == 'https://www.mywebsite.com'){ 
    $('.sidebar').show(); 
  }else {}

})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be fairly simple to include the ad code only when no parameters are given

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: i have edit my question that the code what im using, i want to show in home page and hide in other page, example if link path `https://www.mywebsite.com/?q=somthinghere` Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pathname` property does not include the domain, so you have to test it as `/` (root)...

Below, I used the full `href` property and splitted it to retreive the domain *(which may be useful to you...)* **and** the rest of the string, which is the same as what `pathname` outputs ***without the `/` prefix***.

```js
$(function(){

  var currHref = window.location.href; 
  console.log(currHref);
  
  var currDomain = currHref.split("/").slice(0,3).join("/");
  console.log(currDomain);
  
  var currPath = currHref.split("/").slice(3).join("/");
  console.log(currPath);
  
  
  $('.domain').text('Current domain is : '+ currDomain);
  $('.path').text('Current path is : /'+ currPath);
  
  if(currPath == ''){  // if at domain root, show the ad.
    $('.sidebar').show();
  }else {
    $('.sidebar').hide();
  }
  
  // Just for the demo.
  $("#test").on("click",function(){
    $('.sidebar').show();
  });

});
```

```css
.sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:6em;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:green;
  border-left:2px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="domain"></div>
<div class="path"></div>
<div class="sidebar">Buy my products now!</div>
<button id="test">Show the ad</button>
```

If you don't need to retreive the domain, you can simplify that by using the `pathname` only... But in this case, you have to test for `'/'` instead of empty:

```js
$(function(){

  var currPath = window.location.pathname; 
  console.log(currPath);  
  
  $('.path').text('Current path is : '+ currPath);
  
  if(currPath == '/'){  // if at domain root, show the ad.
    $('.sidebar').show();
  }else {
    $('.sidebar').hide();
  }
  
  // Just for the demo.
  $("#test").on("click",function(){
    $('.sidebar').show();
  });

});
```

```css
.sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:6em;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:green;
  border-left:2px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="path"></div>
<div class="sidebar">Buy my products now!</div>
<button id="test">Show the ad</button>
```

In the above SO snippets, the page `pathname` is `/js`...
;)